# Ionic 4 Sign In With Apple

Tags: ionic-framework, sign

Please, could you help me?
I want to add Sign in with ionic 4 but no documentation I found only this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple but somehow I couldn't use.

Many Thanks

Comment: have you checked its Github repo? [link](https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple#readme)

Comment: Yes, I checked, but after installing SignInWithApple not recognize.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you are getting some sort of error, can you show that error?

Comment: Yes, please
 Property 'SignInWithApple' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.

Comment: declare let cordova: any; at the top of your file where you are using it.

Comment: I did it but that's not helped me ((

Comment: having same error?

Comment: Error is some "Property 'SignInWithApple' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'."
Somehow it should be added like this

constructor(public signInWithApple: SignInWithApple) {}

this.signInWithApple.signin()

but SignInWithApple I could not import like this

import {SignInWithApple} from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple';

Many Thanks

Comment: @DavidKhachatryan Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
import { SignInWithApple, AppleSignInResponse, AppleSignInErrorResponse, ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest } from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple/ngx';


  constructor(private signInWithApple: SignInWithApple) { }


    this.signInWithApple.signin({
      requestedScopes: [
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeEmail
      ]
    })
    .then((res: AppleSignInResponse) => {
      // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user
      alert('Send token to apple for verification: ' + res.identityToken);
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((error: AppleSignInErrorResponse) => {
      alert(error.code + ' ' + error.localizedDescription);
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: I have white screen on the browser when add this import and the dependence to the contructor.

Comment: Iv got this error Cannot find name 'SignInWithApple'

Answer (score 2):

Example if you are also using Firebase

Install native plugin

`npm i --save @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple`

In your application

```js
import {
  SignInWithApple,
  AppleSignInResponse,
  AppleSignInErrorResponse,
  ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest
} from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple';

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

async nativeAppleAuth(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const appleCredential: AppleSignInResponse = await SignInWithApple.signin({
      requestedScopes: [
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeEmail
      ]
    });
    const credential = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
      appleCredential.identityToken
    );
    const response = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    console.log('Login successful', response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: How to get user details after authentication?